# How to make the jitter by using vegalite package

Tags: julia, vega-lite, julia-plots

I got the following graph for each job title with salary in box plot:
[image]

[image]

so there are some outliers here, presented as dot, I want to make some jitters like this for each job title have outliers:

[image]

Is there any way I can do it with Vegalite package?
can someone gives me some advices please?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: If I'm correct, your desired output is from `StatisticalGraphics.jl` package. In that case,use that package to create your box plot and then use its `vegalite` spec and push it back to `VegaLite.jl`.

Comment: yes its from StatisticalGraphics.jl package! I am relatively new to julia, can you please be more specific about it? I understand creation of box plot but what does use vegalite spec and push it back to vegalit.jl means? Thanks in advance!!

Comment: added an answer

Answer (score 2):

using `StatisticalGraphics.jl` package:

```
using InMemoryDatasets
using StatisticalGraphics
ds=Dataset(x=[1,2],y=[2,3])
sgplot(ds,Line(x=:x,y=:y))
```

if you run this code you'll see
[image]
press "view source" to see `VegaLite` specs.

Answer (score 1):

You can read a solution for jittering here:

https://github.com/vega/vega-lite/issues/4703

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply! I have tried that, with code:  new |> @vlplot(mark={:point},transform=[{calculate="random()", as="random"}],x=:job_title,y=:salary_in_usd,yoffset={field="random",type="quantitative"},width=800,height=400), but this is point graph, I want to have box plot but only jitters to the outliers(like the last graph), do you have any ideas how to achieve that? Thanks!

Comment: I haven't done it before but if you can provide a working Vega spec in the Vega editor along with data, I could try and take a look.

Comment: Goodevening, here's my code for processing data: 
import Downloads                                                                                 
                               using DLMReader, VegaLite, InMemoryDatasets                       data=Downloads.download("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/akshdfyehd/salary/main/ds_salaries.csv")                             ds=filereader(data,emptycolname=true)                                  new=filter(ds,:employment_type,by= ==("FT"))                        select!(new,:job_title,:salary_in_usd)